# Gameplay-affecting LOD in a multiplayer UDK environment

Tags: udk, level-of-detail

There is an idea of developing a proof-of-concept multiplayer environmental exploration game that has *varying levels of level of detail* in terms of not just how objects are represented, but *what objects are presented to each player, depending on the assigned parameters to each player present in the world* governed by certain skill-sets. After the initial discussion, it was decided to to give Unreal Development Kit a try for building this concept project. We know that in all major engines LOD settings can affect meshes and textures just fine, but normally it's bound to graphics settings for the whole game.

**Example of the implementation:** Player A focuses on imagery and and thus sees the world in higher level of detail - there are better textures and better meshes visible, whilst player B focuses on audio clues and thus is enabled to hear more sounds that are triggered by various events.*

Is it possible to implement such a mechanism in a multiplayer Unreal Engine 3 environment?

Since I'm relatively new to both game development and UDK's capabilities, it would be greatly appreciated if I could get advice on any possible show-stoppers for this idea. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UDK doesn't have anything built in that does exactly what you say. However, it's certainly possible since you can conditionally play/display sounds/meshes. For example, using Kismet, the conditionals are [pretty simple](http://udn.epicgames.com/Three/KismetExamples.html#Conditions).

It'll certainly be a lot of work, though it's unclear from your requirements if that's a "showstopper". There's nothing that's technically impossible with what you're suggesting.